# Does threadlocal variable work with JBoss drools

Tags: java, jboss, drools, mvel

I am using JBoss drools 5.5.0.final with mvel2 (2.1.3) dialect

I am facing issue as thread local variable set before ksession.fireAllRules(), but the thread local variable seems to be unset within flow.

Is using threadlocal variables in Drools/mvel is bad practice? What are possible reasons and options.

EDIT:I access this threadlocal varibale in java class which gets invoked through drools. Its kind of application specific execution context information stored in that threadlocal variable.

This problem is observed in **high concurrency**(more than 4 threads executing same process)

Comment: And what do you store in that `ThreadLocal`? Note that as its name implies, you'll have one instance of it per thread

Comment: Check whether this access happens while you are still in the thread that calls fireAllRules which should be the thread with the ThreadLocal being set.

Comment: @laune yes ThreadLocal context is getting accessed while rule is under execution

Comment: All right, but is it the same thread that has set the ThreadLocal?

Comment: @laune I see this problem only during high concurrency, I a reduce to 1 execution at a time there is no problem